# Using a helper with a provider-less, 12.5-style custom resource (LWRP) in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lwrp

cookbook/libraries/rn_helper.rb:

```
def sample_func
  puts "woohoo"
end
```

cookbook/resources/rn.rb:

```
action :create do
  sample_func
end
```

The above code works perfectly. The below code does not:

cookbook/libraries/rn_helper.rb:

```
module SampleModule
  def sample_func
    puts "woohoo"
  end
end
```

cookbook/resources/rn.rb:

```
extend SampleModule

action :create do
  sample_func
end
```

The error is as follows:
     `NameError: custom resource[usr.bin.foo] had an error: NameError: No resource, method, or local variable named 'sample_func' for 'LWRP resource some_resource from cookbook some_cookbook action provider "usr.bin.foo"'`

This is a new-style, Chef 12.5 custom resource -- there is no provider file. Everything is described in the resource itself.

How can I "modularize" my helpers using the new-style custom resource syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the internal "action class" to add methods:

```
action_class do
  include SampleModule
end
```

Comment: FYI modules included this way work in actions, but are not available to ``load_current_value`` method.  However you can ``extend SampleModule`` inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend within the action block. When passing a block in like this, a different class than the top-level one is being yielded. Because you are using the function within block that was yielded that class, you need to extend that class to include the methods you need.

You should be able to do that by adding `extend SampleModule` as the first line within the action block.

Comment: Workable, but using `action_class` is probably a lot clearer.